# Why isn't docker commit saving data in my mongo database container?

Tags: mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file that links a seed script with a mongo image from docker's public registry.  I can populate the database with:

```
docker-compose up
docker-compose run seed_script
```

I can connect to this mongo container with the `mongo` cli from my host system and verify that the seed script is working and there's data in the database.

When I'm done seeding, I can see the mongo container ID with `docker ps`.  I stop the container by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>c</kbd> in the docker-compose terminal and commit the changes to the mongo container:

```
docker commit <mongo container ID> mongo-seeded-data
```

However, when I run that container individually, it's empty:

```
docker run -p 27017:27017 mongo-seeded-data

mongo
> show dbs
local  0.000GB
```

If I bring up the docker-compose containers again and use my host mongo client, I can see the data:

```
docker-compose up

mongo
> show dbs
seeded_db  0.018GB
local      0.000GB
```

I committed the container with the data in it. Why is it not there when I bring up the container?  What is `docker-compose` doing differently than `docker run`?

Comment: Most likely the mongo image defines a volume, and `docker commit` does not save data inside volumes.

Comment: Yep, official mongo images [define own volumes](https://github.com/docker-library/mongo/blob/4bb17b336a05ad85c9bf83b103d21529e27e62f9/3.2/Dockerfile#L60). I was able to solve this issue creating my own Dockerfile for mongo (just copied official and deleted VOLUME directives), and using docker-compose with [named volumes](https://madcoda.com/2016/03/docker-named-volume-explained/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is a VOLUME defined in it.

`docker commit` saves the content of the overlay fs as a new image, but VOLUMES transcend the overlay fs. That's why it doesn't get saved.

I had the same problem in the past and resolved patching the mongo image by using a different data directory, so that the data would get written inside the container instead of the VOLUME.